# compiles succesfully on codeblocks 13.12 but compilation error on ideone or spoj

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I wrote a code for [spoj.com](http://www.spoj.com/)

**Adding reverse number**

> We have to input two numbers reverse both and add, and finally print the reverse of the sum.

I have scanned both numbers in form of string and used atoi and itoa functions several times.

This code works fine on **Codeblocks 13.12** but shows compilation error on **ideone** or **spoj(c++ 5.3.2).**

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':

prog.cpp:38:25: error: 'itoa' was not declared in this scope
         itoa(sum,ssum,10);
```

Also am not able to find which `g++` compiler **Codeblocks** is using.
I also tried adding `stdlib.h` but it also don't work.

This is my code in c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,num1,num2,sum,ln1,ln2,lns,i,j;
    char snum1[100],snum2[100],ssum[100];
    char stemp;
    cin>>t; // scaning number of test cases
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>snum1>>snum2; // scanning number 1 and number 2 as string
        ln1=strlen(snum1); //finding length of string of number 1
        ln2=strlen(snum2); // finding length of string of number 1
        for(i=0,j=ln1-1;i<ln1/2;i++,j--) // reversing the string of number 1
        {
           stemp=snum1[i];
            snum1[i]=snum1[j];
            snum1[j]=stemp;
        }
        for(i=0,j=ln2-1;i<ln2/2;i++,j--) // reversing string of number 2
        {
           stemp=snum2[i];
            snum2[i]=snum2[j];
            snum2[j]=stemp;
        }

        num1=atoi(snum1); //converting reversed string of number 1 to integer as num1
        num2=atoi(snum2); // converting reversed string of number 2 to integer as num 2

        sum=num1+num2; // finding sum

        itoa(sum,ssum,10); // converting sum(integer) t0 string
        lns=strlen(ssum); // finding length of string of sum
        for(i=0,j=lns-1;i<lns/2;i++,j--) // reversing the sum string
        {
           stemp=ssum[i];
            ssum[i]=ssum[j];
            ssum[j]=stemp;
        }
        sum=atoi(ssum); // finally converting the reversed sum string to integer
        cout<<sum<<endl; // final printing of result

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: There's no standard `itoa` function. Use e,g, [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: So tl;dr of the above comments: *"This is my code in c++"* No, it's not. That's why some C++ compilers reject it. Get a better learning resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that itoa is not a function defined by the standard.
You need to start the file with

```
#include <iostream>   // Define cin and cout
#include <stdlib.h>   // Define atoi
#include <string>     // Define to_string and std::string
```

Next, remember the great commandment:  **Don't Repeat Yourself**.  You reverse a string three times.  You read a string from cin, reverse it, and convert to integer twice.

```
#include <iostream>   // Define cin and cout
#include <string>     // Define to_string and std::string, and stoi.

using namespace std;

static int reverse(string snum) // Reverse and convert to integer
{                               // NB.  Takes argument by VALUE.
    const auto len = snum.length();
    for(size_t i=0,j=len-1; i<j; i++,j--) // or use std::reverse.
    {
        const char stemp = snum[i];
        snum[i] = snum[j];
        snum[j] = stemp;
    }
    return stoi(snum);
}

static int read_reversed()
{
    std::string snum;
    cin>>snum;
    return reverse(snum);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;// scaning number of test cases
    while(t--)
    {
        const int num1 = readreversed();
        const int num2 = readreversed();
        const int sum=num1+num2;

        string ssum = to_string(sum);

        cout << reverse(ssum) << endl; // Reverse string and print.
    }
    return 0;
}
```